# Sending e-mail to server with external MX

Tags: email, mx-record

Is it possible to send an e-mail to a server when the MX for the domain is not on this server?
I have the following set up:

- Server A with domain domain.com configured
- GMail as the Mail Exchanger

I want to set up an e-mail address to which I can send e-mails whose content will then be stored in a database. As far as I know, for that I would need to set up a postfix filter that runs a script when receiving an e-mail from said address. But for that, the server first needs to get the e-mail, which it currently doesn't.

Is there any way to forward the e-mail from the external MX to the actual server, or to completely bypass the external MX for a list of addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by setting up a subdomain for domain.com that has its own DNS zone. So the set up is now as follows:

- Server A with domain domain.com and subdomain services.domain.com configured
- GMail as MX for domain.com
- Server A as MX for services.domain.com
- E-Mail Address mail@services.domain.com

This seems to run fine now, but I am not sure if that is the best solution.